# Why does my escript crash the interpreter?

Tags: erlang

I have a tiny program that reads a csv file (100M). The problem is that my program makes the Erlang interpreter crash:

```
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
eheap_alloc: Cannot reallocate 3563526520 bytes of memory (of type "heap").
Aborted
```

Here is the program:

```
readlines(FileName) ->
    {ok, Device} = file:open(FileName, [read]),
    try get_all_lines(Device)
      after file:close(Device)
    end.


get_all_lines(Device) ->
    case io:get_line(Device, "") of
        eof -> [];
        Line -> [Line | get_all_lines(Device)]
    end.
```

And I do:

```
Path="...csv".
Lines=tut6:readlines(Path).
```

And this procudes a crash.

Can someone please tell me what the problem is? Maybe something is wrong with my program? How can I avoid the crashes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does it work with a smaller file?

Comment: What are you doing with each line individually? You may have more success by processing the file line by line instead of collecting all lines into a list.

Comment: @A. Sarid. It does work on a smaller file.

Comment: @nu-ex. Yes you're probably right. But in any case, I need to store the CSV contents in list and hash tables and such. So maybe the memory usage will still make the interpreter crash.
Did you ever hear of something like this before?

Comment: Loading 100MB file into memory before acting on it isn't a requirement I have encountered yet. Could you tell us more about what you are trying to do? You may consider importing the CSV data into a database, such as mnesia, DETS or even PostgreSQL or MySQL and fetching as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you realize that 3563526520 is 3.3 GB? How much memory does your system have? The gigantic memory consumption stems from the fact that you have chosen the least optimal algorithm for reading the lines:

1. You try to read all the lines to the memory before acting on them
2. You chose to represent the text as list, which uses 8 bytes for each character read from the file (or 16 bytes on 64-bit systems)
3. You don't use tail-recursion which means the compiler can't optimize your code to be more memory efficient

So, to fix the code:

1. Read one line at at time, then parse and process it and store as Erlang terms rather than the raw input data
2. Read lines as binaries, as suggested by Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil
3. Make the function reading the file tail-recursive

[Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion) has an excellent discussion about tail recursive functions if you want to know how to properly implement such functions.

If the function was written in a tail-recursive manner the whole algorithm could look like this:

```
get_all_lines(Device) ->
    get_all_lines(Device, []).

get_all_lines(Device, List) ->
    case io:get_line(Device, "") of
        eof ->
            lists:reverse(List);
        Line ->
            Data = process_line(Line),
            get_all_lines(Device, [Data | List])
    end.
```

Comment: Hi Amiramix. How should I represent the text? Could you please give an example? :)

Comment: @JeniaIvanov if you open the file in binary mode `[read, binary]` then any read operation from the device will return a binary instead of a list (including `io:get_line/2` from your example code). If you want to know how to handle binaries then this introduction should help: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
{ok, Device} = file:open(FileName, [read, binary]),
```

and then rethink what you are really up to.